# InfoPath 2010 Validation not Working As Expected

Tags: infopath, validation

I have an issue with Validation in InfoPath 2010. I'm using IP 2010 with 2013 SP List. Below is step by step of the issue I'm encountering:

- Below is part of a form in IP. The controls are a Radio Button (Yes/No) for Functional Review and Review Approval (TextBox)

[image]

- What I want to accomplish is if "Yes" is selected in the form, then the User is ***Required*** to enter something in the Review Approval textBox. So I create a Validation Rule on the TextBox. Essentially, if FunctionalReview=Yes, then User is required to enter something in textbox shown below:

[image]

- I preview the IP form and test the Validation. As shown below, the Validation kicks in when "Yes" is selected from Radio Button:

[image]

- However, when I enter something in the TextBox and click Save, it gives me an error shown below:

[image]

As stated earlier, the expectation is that if "Yes" is selected from the Radio Button then the User is ***Required*** to enter something in the TextBox prior to clicking Save. If the User enters anything in the TextBox when "Yes" is selected, the form should allow the User to click Save instead of displaying a validation error.

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong in the Validation? It does not make sense as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another condition to check if the Review Approval field is blank. So your conditions end up being FunctionalReview = "Yes" and ReviewApproval is Blank. This way when text is entered, your condition is set to false, and the validation goes away.